# Strange PHP PDO error - unexpected null

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, checkbox

I can't see why MySQL is causing PHP PDO to throw this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
>   'disclaimer' cannot be null'[...]

There's quite a bit of code involved in this particular form front and back-end so so I'll just quote the relevant bits.

HTML:

```
<label for="disclaimer" class="container ten columns">*Blah blah legalese</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="dislcaimer" value="disclaimer">
```

PHP:

```
  if(!isset($_POST['fname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['sname']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        // and so on ...   
        !isset($_POST['dislcaimer']) ||
          (
          !isset($_POST['mf'])&&!isset($_POST['me'])&&!isset($_POST['ms'])&&!isset($_POST['wf'])&&!isset($_POST['we'])&&!isset($_POST['ws'])
        )
      )
    {
        died('We are sorry, but you appear to have left at least one of the mandatory fields blank.');    
}
```

[...]

```
$disclaimer = $_POST['disclaimer']; // variable initialisation
```

PHP/PDO:

```
  $data = array($first_name, $last_name, $email_from, $telephone, $dateofbirth, $licence, $club, $countynm, $mf, $me, $ms, $wf, $we, $ws, $party, $disclaimer);
  $STH = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO competitor (fname, sname, email, phone, dob, licence, club, country, mf, me, ms, wf, we, ws, party, disclaimer) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $STH->execute($data);
```

MYSQL:

[image: part of database- phpmyadmin]

I just don't get it. On debugging the checkbox returns NULL, but surely it should have triggered the automatic error generated when mandatory fields are not filled in? Am I handling checkboxes entirely wrong in this setting? For other, optional checkboxes, I'm assigning some integer to them in the event that they are unticked (e.g. '0') so that this sort of error does not crop up. Do I need to do the same for this, but assign it maybe '1' if it is set...? :/

Comment: "If the checkbox was returning NULL" --- how about stopping **guessing** and starting debugging? `var_dump($disclaimer);`

Comment: print_r $data array before execute. You will know then.

Comment: @zerkms: okay- it definitely *is* NULL... which is progress, but doesn't answer either why it is NULL, nor why it isn't caught by the code designed to catch unset information.

Comment: @Duncan: it's `NULL` because it hasn't been sent. The next debugging step: take firebug (or chrome dev tools) and look what actually has been sent in POST. The checkboxes values are only sent if they are checked. The simplest workaround - is to create hidden with the same name and value equal to your "unchecked" value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo here:

```
name="dislcaimer"
```

and here

```
!isset($_POST['dislcaimer'])
```

but not here:

```
$disclaimer = $_POST['disclaimer'];
```

one more thing, after correcting that typo, `$_POST['disclaimer']` will have value `disclaimer` but you have tinyint field for that, so you should use `value="1"` in input.

Comment: same typo in both html and php.. some feat I guess. And the value issue is a complete brain-fart on my part

Answer (score 2):

There are two tings for you no know

1. checkboxes are not sent to the server when not checked.
2. You have to always be in touch with every error occurred.

For the latter rule add this line into your bootstrap file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

So, you will be notified of the every error in general, and of the missing `$_POST['disclaimer'];` in this case.
So, you have to define it manually in this case

By the way, if it's just a checkbox, that prevents data from save when absent, I see no point in storing it in the database.

Comment: In relation to saving such data: that might be true. It doesn't really serve any useful purpose; but as it is a disclaimer the db would officially record that people have signed off on the disclaimer, rather than the logical juncture that people must have signed off in order for their information be recorded.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your checkbox the value that is posted is disclaimer. That is not a integer as you aspect in your database. You could set this to 1 or you have to change this in php.

In php you can do something like this to make it work:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['disclaimer'] == 'disclaimer') {
//checked
$disclaimer = 1;
} else {
// not checked
$disclaimer = 0;
}
```